# How to create and read a sequence in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, orm, hsqldb

I need to use a sequence to get a unique value. The production code uses postgres but I would like to access it via Hibernate so that I can test this with HSQLDB.

How can I create and read a sequence in Hibernate?

Comment: It's too bad hibernate seems to *not support* sequences (auto creating them via hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto etc.) seems the only way to do it is via raw sql queries, which isn't as portable, and doesn't have auto create :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `Dialect` (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.java).

It contains code to determine whether your database supports sequences (`supportsSequences()`) and methods to create and drop them ('getCreateSequenceString(String sequenceName)').

Unfortunately, there is no clean way to get the dialect from the session; see [How to get Hibernate dialect during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181397/how-to-get-hibernate-dialect-during-runtime)

**[OLD Answer]**

You could try to reuse the code from `HibernateDialect` but the main API doesn't offer this. Your best bet is probably to wrap this in an interface and then use different implementations depending on your dialect.

Comment: could you elaborate on using the code from HibernateDialect here please?

Comment: @rogerdpack: Thanks for the ping, I updated my answer