# How to get Hibernate dialect during runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence.xml, dialect

In my application, I use Hibernate with SQL Server database, so I set

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect">
```

in my persistence.xml.

In some case, I want to sort records with NULL include, I use keyword NULLS FIRST.
Because it is not supported by default by CriteriaQuery/CriteriaBuilder in Hibernate, then I use Interceptor to modify the native query.
The problem is, keyword NULLS FIRST is not supported in SQL Server, so I use keyword:

```
case when column_name is null then 0 else 1 end, column_name
```

If I want to migrate database from SQL Server to Oracle (for example), then I need to put if-else in my Interceptor, choosing which dialect I am using, right?

This is how I illustrate them:

```
String dialect = ..............
if (dialect.equals("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect")) { // get SQL Server dialect
     // put keyword "case when column_name is null then 0 else 1 end, column_name"
} else {
     // put keyword "NULLS FIRST/LAST"
}
```

How I can get the dialect configuration (in persistence.xml) during runtime?

Comment: another link about NULLS FIRST keyword : https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-465

Comment: I use Interceptor based on this article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683174/hibernate-order-by-with-nulls-last

Comment: These links may help you to get dialect info from SessionFactory; [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571928/retrieve-auto-detected-hibernate-dialect) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742617/resolve-sql-dialect-using-hibernate)

Comment: thank you Wundwin Born, I got the solution on the second link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742617/resolve-sql-dialect-using-hibernate

Answer (score 6):

The following works well for me for accessing the dialect in a Java EE application running in WildFly 14:

```java
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl;

...

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

...

final Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
final SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) session.getSessionFactory();
final Dialect dialect = sessionFactory.getJdbcServices().getDialect();
logger.info("Dialect: {}", dialect);
```

You need to add `hibernate-core` dependency with *provided* scope to `pom.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Spring+hibernate, try this

```
@Autowired@Qualifier("sessionFactory") org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory; //Suppose using hibernate 3
```

and in your method:

```
sessionFactory.getHibernateProperties().get("hibernate.dialect")
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer from this post : [Resolve SQL dialect using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742617/resolve-sql-dialect-using-hibernate)

Thank you for @Dewfy,

here is the solution:

```
//take from current EntityManager current DB Session
Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
//Hibernate's SessionFactoryImpl has property 'getDialect', to
//access this I'm using property accessor:
Object dialect = 
       org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(
          session.getSessionFactory(), "dialect");
//now this object can be casted to readable string:
if (dialect.toString().equals("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect")) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: This would be quicker and less painful : String dialect = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getProperties().getOrDefault("hibernate.dialect", "").toString();

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work in my case. This worked:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

Properties properties = new Configuration().configure().getProperties();
String dialect = properties.getProperty("hibernate.dialect");
```